# Python&Excel: Issue when trying to run a macro / refresh pivots

Tags: python, excel, win32com, xlwings

I am generating an Excel with Knime and afterwards I am using python to make some adjustments to the file.
I am taking the data from the output of Knime and pasting them into a pre-formatted Template.xlsm which has several pivot tables to be refreshed after the new data have been pasted. Everything is working till the last step, when I need to refresh the pivots.

I have tried different solutions:

- creating a macro and a button in the Template.xlsm so that when the user opens the file he can directly refresh all the pivots --> this does not work as I am using *openpyxl* and when the new file is being generated all the shapes are being deleted
- refresh the pivots directly with python by using *win32com* (with the code below) --> it does not work as I am getting **PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied.**

```
import win32com.client 
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.workbooks.open("path\file.xlsm")
xl.Visible = True
wb.RefreshAll()
xl.Quit()
```

- running directly the macro with python. I tried both, before saving the file and also after having saved it (basically reading it again and trying to run the macro). --> it does not work as I get always the error: **PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied.**

```
import xlwings as xw
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("excelsheet.xlsm"), ReadOnly=1)
xl.Application.Run("excelsheet.xlsm!modulename.macroname")
xl.Application.Save() the
xl.Application.Quit()
```

I think this is related to the fact that in my organization we have a compulsory sensitivity level labelling in all the files. However, I found it strange that, while I am still working on it with the script (I mean before saving it and therefore generating the final file.xlsm), I cannot run the macro.

- I tried also to set up automatically the sensivity level by assigning the label ID with python (with the code below) --> I keep getting the error: **PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied.**

```
wb = xw.Book('file.xlsm')
labelinfo = wb.api.SensitivityLabel.CreateLabelInfo()
labelinfo.AssignmentMethod = 2
labelinfo.Justification = 'init'
labelinfo.LabelId = 'YOUR-ID-GOES-HERE'
wb.api.SensitivityLabel.SetLabel(labelinfo, labelinfo)
```

Do you have any suggestions or way to eventually bypass the sensitivity labelling?

This is the error that I keep getting:

```
Executing the Python script failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 208, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\py3_knime\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 407, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\py3_knime\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 291, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\py3_knime\lib\zipfile.py", line 1248, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C: ...\file.xlsm'
```

Comment: "I am taking the data from the output of Knime and pasting them into a pre-formatted Template.xlsm" - are you pasting the data programmatically?

Comment: I am doing an hard copy from a xlsx to a xlsm which have the same table/structure. I have a for loop which iterates on rows and columns.

Comment: To be clear, on the `win32com` code, you are getting the error on `RefreshAll`? Or are you getting it on `Open`?

Answer (score 0):

Please close all Excel instances with windows Task Manager before testing. `workbook.Close` is needed to save the change.

```py
# Env: pywin32 v305, Python 3.11, Excel 365
import win32com.client 
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
xl_file = r"d:/temp/py.xlsm"
wb = xl.workbooks.open(xl_file)
xl.Visible = True
wb.RefreshAll()
wb.Close(SaveChanges=1)
xl.Quit()
```

Remove `ReadOnly=1`, the code works well too.

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl_file = r"d:/temp/py.xlsm"
wb = xl.workbooks.open(xl_file)
xl.Application.Run("py.xlsm!mdl1.demo")
# save active workbook
wb.Close(SaveChanges=1)
xl.Quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It does not work yet. I keep getting the error I have just posted above in the description.

Comment: Create a new xlsm and test the code. The Excel file might be locked coz Excel application crash.